# Azure Ratecard API returning incomplete json object

Tags: azure

I've been using Azure Ratecard API for programmatically fetching the prices of azure virtual machine instances. Initially, everything was working fine, but for past few days I've been getting incomplete json response when I send a GET request to Azure Ratecard API using the following URL -

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2016-08-31-preview&%24filter=OfferDurableId+eq+'MS-AZR-0003P'+and+Currency+eq+'USD'+and+Locale+eq+'en-US'+and+RegionInfo+eq+'US'
```

For authorization, I am passing the access token in headers of the request like this -

```
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can confirm that this issue is persistent for them as well and is from the azure API's end.

Comment: Is there a `nextLink` at the end of the response?

Comment: No, there is no nextLink or pagination URL in the response. The response abruptly ends without proper closures of JSON structure. So for example, if the expected output would have been `{"data":{"key":"value","key":"value"}}` then right now it's returning something like `{"data":{"key":"value","key"`